# Automute on Zoom

Tags: software

Is there a setting where you can auto-mute when joining zoom? I've tried searching for a solution and don't even know if it exists. I often join large zoom meetings or webinars and forget to mute. It would be a lot easier if I was muted upon entering the Zoom room.

Comment: This isn't a workplace question, but yes on the windows desktop app under the "Audio" settings there's a "Mute microphone when joining a meeting" setting. I don't know about mobile or other OSes

Comment: What would be a good channel for this topic? @RobinClower

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about use of software not specific to the workplace.

Comment: You can ask questions about the web client on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoom.us).

Comment: For the record, I disagree that mute settings on Zoom counts as a workplace policy or legal advice.

Comment: Sorry, [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zoom) would have been the place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably off-topic for this forum, but in Zoom under Preferences, go into Audio settings. There should be an option for "Mute mic when joining a meeting".

Definitely a handy thing to have enabled.

Comment: I'm not sure why you got downvotes, this is the correct way to solve it, and it's better IMO to answer a bad question quickly and vote to close than it is just to vote to close.

Comment: @RobinClower I guess people don't like I answered an off-topic question. I figured it would get deleted eventually, but I might as well help OP out even if this isn't the right place for the question. Besides, having people know how to use Zoom effectively does make the workplace better for everyone involved. Oh well.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and upvoted. but people probably downvoted your answer to discourage the posting of off-topic question.

Comment: *"I figured it would get deleted eventually..."* Well, the OP can't delete it now; it has an answer that's gotten at least one downvote. People can, however, continue downvoting the question.